# Questions cannot have duplicate choice values Google Sheet to Google Form error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form that has a Question that depending upon an answer will direct you to further questions. I have created a section in the google form. When I am trying to update the google spreadsheet to the form using app script I am getting an error saying "**Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values**"
[image: The sheet which has the column which is same as from the google form]
All of the column in the google sheet are same name used in the google form and all are dropdown in the google form
I have the app script as below

```js
const populateGoogleForms = () => {
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = "Form Data";
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "1bl179GkeU58rq6jNj_aiSFlORGB8j7e36CtKE3drIk4";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const [header, ...data] = ss.getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);});

  FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID).getItems().map((item) => ({item,values: choices[item.getTitle()],})).filter(({ values }) => values).forEach(({ item, values }) => {
      switch (item.getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        default:
        // ignore item
      }
    });
  ss.toast("Google Form Updated !!");
};
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your sample Google Form for better replication? When I tested your script on my end, I can update my test form's choices without getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message of `Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values`, for example, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
header.forEach((title, i) => {choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);});
```

#### To:

```
header.forEach((title, i) => {
  choices[title] = [...new Set(data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e))];
});
```

- I thought that the values of `data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e)` might include the duplicated values. So I proposed this modification. This is just my guess.

#### Reference:

- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)